# Automatically set category based on wordpress post visibility?

Tags: wordpress

I've been looking for a way to automatically append a category everytime a post is set to private. I've seen several of ways of doing this for custom post types but i've yet to figure out a way how to achieve this with post visibility.

Any ideas?

Comment: create a function with ```wp_set_post_categories``` hook into  ```save_post```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filter should do the job.

```
function add_categories_automatically($postID) {
    if(get_post_status($postID) == 'private'){
        $catsID = array(5);
        wp_set_post_categories($postID, $catsID, true);
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'add_categories_automatically');
```

This will check the post status when it is published. If the status is private, specified categories will be appended to the post.

**Be careful,** as wp_set_post_categories will overwrite any existing categories already assigned to the post unless the third parameter is set to true: [wp_set_post_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories)

Comment: Thank you but the code didn't work on my test server, does it have to be 4.4.1?

Comment: Change publish_post by save_post. Right now only works when you publish a post, but doesn't work if the post is already published. This should make it work any time you save a post